# Setting file content instead of path for truststore

Tags: java, oracle, java-8, java-io, truststore

I am connecting to oracle ssl listener via my java code. The java code is running in AWS Lambda. In order to connect to oracle via SSL port , I need to pass the cwallet.sso certificate. This certificate is base64 encoded and stored in a vault. I am able to get the contents of the certificate as String from the vault. I need to base64 decode and use the contents to connect to oracle.Below the code that I use in my local machine to connect to oracle ssl port. Since I am getting the data as stream from vault , is there a way I can supply the certificate (cwallet.sso) without having to create a file?

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());                                                                                           
      Security.addProvider(new oracle.security.pki.OraclePKIProvider());                                                                                             
      String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=<hostname>)(PORT=1522))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=<SID>)))";      
      java.util.Properties info = new java.util.Properties();                                                                                                        
      ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();                                                                                                         
      info.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", Paths.get(classLoader.getResource("certs/cwallet.sso").toURI()).toString());                                      
      info.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "SSO");                                                                                                       
      info.setProperty("user", "username");                                                                                                                        
      info.setProperty("password", "password");                                                                                                                       

      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, info);                                                                                                      
      Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();                                                                                                                       
      ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery("select * from table where rownum < 10");
```

Comment: Can you give some more details?

Comment: @SazzadurRahaman added few more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general it would be possible to load a certificate from memory, for example as outlined [here](https://jcalcote.wordpress.com/2010/06/22/managing-a-dynamic-java-trust-store/), however in current context we are limited by what Oracle driver supports.

Configuration of the driver is described [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/wp-oracle-jdbc-thin-ssl-130128.pdf) and it does not look like anything besides file based trust stores is supported. It is hard to provide more definite answer as Oracle driver is closed source.

Comment: Thanks @hgrey. I ended up creating a temporary file in the filesystem and referenced that file.